# Changing headers and saving file

Tags: php, security, curl, google-chrome-devtools, wget

When I am in example.com/name.php?id=1&image=33 I can see a certain jpg but I cant save it. In chrome dev tools I can see the path to the jpg but I cant access it directly with the url.

How can I use wget or curl (or other in php) to save this file? I think I would need to curl the jpg link but sending the info to the server of the path where I can see the image but I just cant do it.

If someone knows how to do this please explain with detailed info since I think I am lacking a lot of knowledge here.

Answer (score 1):

> but I cant save it

How are you trying to save it? Have you tried disabling Javascript in the browser

> In chrome dev tools I can see the path to the jpg....How can I use wget or curl

By replicating the successful request headers. It's further possible that you may have to replicate one of the preceding requests.

Someone has put some effort into making it difficult for you to retrieve this content - implying that you may be breaching the terms of use by downloading the file.

Comment: Do you have an example of how I can fully replicate those headers with curl or wget?

Comment: curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ('User-Agent'=>$u, 'Referer'=>$r, 'Accept'=>$a, 'Cookie'=>$c)); See the PHP Curl pages for what goes before and after this, and your webdeveloper tools for values for $r, $a, $u and $c

Comment: I went to google dev tools and copied the request as cURL. Then pasted in the cmd of windows and the request is denied. I think that cURL isn't the tool to do this because I think that cURL always requires a direct request. For some reason I need to "be" at a certain URL and request the jpg from there. I have no idea how I can do this with cURL or any other tool. Fiddler allows me to get the image but not with a "direct" request to the file